# How to write eslint plugin to validate named import aliases

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to write a plugin (or use existing) that will validate all lodash named import aliases begin with an _.

Valid:

```
import { get as _get, has as _has } from ‘lodash’;
```

Invalid

```
import { get, has } from ‘lodash’;
```

Comment: Yes, rule and or plugin. Whatever is the most direct way to accomplish this.

Comment: This doesn't provide the answer you're looking for, but may be relevant for other readers or useful if you decide to write your own rule. See [`lodash/import-scope`](https://github.com/wix/eslint-plugin-lodash/blob/master/docs/rules/import-scope.md) and possibly [`import/named`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/named.md)